# Quit [alternating] [alternate]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate) and [alternating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternating) seem to be completely pointless. All the questions involved are about alternating something or using an alternate something, but they don't really have any specific meaning that I can figure out that is consistent between the posts.

[See [alternate] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate?sort=newest)

If I wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379142/what-tags-are-used-with-tagname-and-how-many-times?TagName=alternate&opt.withExecutionPlan=true) correctly, then the tags used along with [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate) vary wildly. There is no obvious (to me) consistency.

Also, [60 of 118 posts with the tag 'alternate' have 'alternat' in the title](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379163/post-count-with-tag-and-containing-word-in-the-title?Tag=alternate&Word=alternat), which makes it seem to me that the tag is even more useless.

Oh, and the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/alternate/info) is empty.

Also, the data for [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate) is very similar to the data for [alternating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternating)

Comment: Unless it is the name of some technology or coding standard we should just be rid of it. It seems to only being used when someone is looking for an alternate _something_. It adds nothing to the 10 or so questions I looked at

Comment: The `see [alternate] questions` returns 404.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It's the new navigation which you probably don't have. Here's another ["old" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate?sort=active&pageSize=30).

Comment: Ok, that's the same as clicking on the tag

Comment: I think we can add [tag:alternating] to this (oh and I "fixed" the link before noticing it wasn't broken to begin with, just using the new nav system).

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks. I added it. Also, *'alternat' in the title* is intentional, because **alternat** picks up alternate and alternating

Comment: And then there's [this beautiful example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175011/regexp-function-not-working-with-alternation) with both.